# Heroku Django Gunicorn 'Foreman Start' error

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I'm working through the [Heroku's Django tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) and I got all the way down to '[Using a different WSIG server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#using-a-different-wsgi-server)'.

When I try to use gunicorn I get the following error:

```
requirements.txt
Django==1.4.1
distribute==0.6.28
dj-database-url==0.2.1
psycopg2==2.4.5
gunicorn==0.14.6

Procfile
web: gunicorn djtut.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT

(venv) C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Python\djtut>foreman check
valid procfile detected (web)

(venv) C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Python\djtut>foreman start
10:53:05 web.1  | started with pid 5652
10:53:06 web.1  | exited with code 1
10:53:06 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
10:53:06 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
10:53:06        |   File "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Python\djtut\venv\Scripts\
gunicorn-script.py", line 9, in <module>
(venv) C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Python\djtut>
```

Works fine using the dev server on Heroku. I'm on Windows 7. Any ideas?  I suspect it is an OS issue?

thanks,

AP

Comment: What is line 9 of gunicorn-script.py doing?

Comment: load_entry_point('gunicorn==0.14.6','console_scripts','gunicorn')()

Comment: Hmmm... is gunicorn's folder added to PATH?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Gunicorn doesn't work on Windows.