# django heroku foreman start error code 1

Tags: python, django, heroku, foreman

Following the getting started with django heroku page verbatim. 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

On the foreman start step, foreman is not running correctly.
ProcFile contents,

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi
```

Requirements contents:

```
Django==1.5.1
dj-database-url==0.2.1
gunicorn==0.17.4
psycopg2==2.4.5
```

enter virtual env exactly as tutorial, 
gunicorn, procfile and requirements located in scripts directory below, the wsgi.py file is located in directory hellodjango with pathline `C:\hellodjango2\newvirtualenv\Scripts\hellodjango`

python and python/scripts are located on pathfile.

here is the output

```
(newvirtualenv) C:\hellodjango2\newvirtualenv\Scripts>foreman start
09:48:58 web.1  | started with pid 3580
09:48:58 web.1  | exited with code 1
09:48:58 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? look at: [Gunicorn doesn't run on Windows][1]
(and similar answer [here][2])


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087682/does-gunicorn-run-on-windows
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627885/heroku-django-gunicorn-foreman-start-error

Comment: Looks like you're on windows. Just get a linux virtual machine installed on your machine and use it there if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the today's heroku documentation, it advises you to use:

```
$ heroku local web
```

instead of `foreman`. Can you give it a try?

Another thing you could do to check if everything is working fine is to run the django by itself: `python manage.py runserver`, if its not working, can you add the traceback generated by that call?